# Laravel setting session variable correctly

Tags: laravel

Through an `ajax` call with axios (ajax library) I set a session variable in Laravel 5.5:

```
session()->put('can_visit', true);
```

However, when I check in a next GET request (not with ajax) if that variable exists:

```
return session()->has('can_visit');
```

Result is always false, why is that? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Just set it like this:

```
session(['can_visit' => true]);
```

Setting a default value for that key: (optional)

```
session('can_visit', false);
```

Check if it has a session with:

```
session()->has('can_visit');
```

Then fetch it with:

```
$canVisit = session('can_visit');
var_dump($canVisit);
```

Laravel is doing the heavy lifting for you:

```
function session($key = null, $default = null)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return app('session');
    }

    if (is_array($key)) {
        return app('session')->put($key);
    }

    return app('session')->get($key, $default);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it's not working with an ajax call. Please see my code here: https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction/tree/master/src

Comment: What debug did you try? `dd($data)` before every return and see whats return and what methods get called? Maybe its not a getting issue but a setting issue etc

Comment: Yes, Ive done that couple of times but session variable does not exists anymore. So weird this.